# Document.execCommand do not work as I expected

Tags: javascript

Here is my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Paul Johnson</td>
    <th>Street</th>
    <td>Fake Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>State</th>
    <td>California</td>
    <th>Car</th>
    <td>Cadillac</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My script is executed by mouseenter event:

```
$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {

});
```

Inside it its this toolbar which has inside link object

```
toolbar = $("<div />").css({
    "padding": "5px",
    "background" : "#F8F8F8",
    "borderRadius" : "5px 0 5px 5px"
  });

  var link = $("<a />").css({
    "display" : "block",
    "height" : "20px",
    "width" : "20px",
    "marginBottom" : "5px",
    "background-size" : "100%",
    "position" : "relative"})
    .attr({"target" : "_blank"});
```

My variable `thisNext` does that it get text of next td element

```
  var thisNext = $( $(this).next() ).text();
```

**Question**
Why my var copy do not copy `thisNext` value altrough `console.log` works as I expected?

**Edit :** Goal is, if you click to "copy" object appended for exemple on th Name, to get into clipboard Paul Johnson. If on Street, then copy Fake street and so on.

```
var copy = link.clone().on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ("thisNext ");
    thisNext.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, edited. Hope that is now clear.

Comment: Not sure, where are you appending `link` to your table?

Comment: If user mouseenter od th element. It append toolbar. Inside toolbar is copy object and if you click on it, it should copy text of next td element.

Comment: Ok please try to add you complete code to the OP, so we could test it.

Comment: You mean codepen? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Krqxzx?editors=0010 Try to click on this symbol https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/62r7d1kg84hp15y/copy.png goal is to get into clipboard next td next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116475/discussion-between-karolina-ticha-and-zakaria-acharki).

Comment: What does the mouseover and execCommand have to do with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Pen](http://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/QEgVmz?editors=0010#anon-login)**

The problem come from the line :

```
thisNext.execCommand('copy');
```

The `copy` command copy always the selection so we have to select the content of the td first then execute the comment and finally reset the selection :

```
var copy = link.clone().on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var td = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

    do {
      td = td.nextSibling;
    } while(td && td.nodeType !== 1); // 1 == Node.ELEMENT_NODE

    var range = document.createRange();  

    range.selectNode(td); 

    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    document.execCommand('copy');   

    // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
    // removeRange(range) when it is supported  
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
})
```

**NOTE :** you could check if your browser support the copy command using **[This link](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much